# Pandas group by to aggregate string field

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My df is this:

```
1   2   3
A  abc  ab
A  abc  cc
A  abc  ab
```

I'd like to group by the record to have

```
1   2   3
A  abc  ab
A  abc  cc
```

or even better, have one field with concatenated string:

```
   1  
A_abc_ab
A_abc_cc
```

Pandas GroupBy doesn't seem to work with string:

```
df = df.groupby(['1','2','3'])
```

return

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f4a37549bd0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving from this:

```
1   2   3
A  abc  ab
A  abc  cc
A  abc  ab
```

To this:

```
1   2   3
A  abc  ab
A  abc  cc
```

Doesn't involve grouping at all! you're just dropping duplicates:

```
In [9]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[9]: 
   1    2   3
0  A  abc  ab
1  A  abc  cc
```

You can then use apply to concatenate:

```
In [10]: df.drop_duplicates().apply('_'.join, axis=1)
Out[10]: 
0    A_abc_ab
1    A_abc_cc
dtype: object
```

Comment: `drop_duplicates()' is the right function. Coming from sql I immediately thought to GROUP BY. If the fierst column is intger type you suggest to cast to string and the to use apply?

Comment: @franco_b you can use `df[1] = df[1].apply(str)` to cast to string. And yes, it's either this, or applying a custom function instead of `'_'.join`.

Answer (score 4):

You are not applying `groupby` correctly. Also after `groupby` you have to `group.aggregate()` in order to reduce cells on the basis of some function

Probably you may want this better:

```
df.apply('-'.join, axis=1)
```

which produces

```
0    A-abc-ab
1    A-abc-cc
2    A-abc-ab
dtype: object
```

Of course you can `drop_duplicates` before of after joining